# Syntax Inquiry on usage of LIKE

Tags: sql

I have a table called programmes and an attribute called PROGRAMMES_COURSE. One of the course is engineering.

If I were to find the engineering field just by typing eng,what syntax do I use?
I have tried this but I know it's wrong

```
SELECT * FROM programmes WHERE PROGRAMMES_COURSE LIKE 'eng%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROGRAMMES
WHERE PROGRAMMES_COURSE LIKE 'eng%'
```

This query should work without any problems. If it does not find what you need, you should provide more information so we can find out where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROGRAMMES
WHERE PROGRAMMES_COURSE LIKE '%eng%'
```